# Visual Studio 2015 can't build Windows 10 universal app?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I was using Visual Studio 2015 RC and building Windows 10 App with no problem. Once I upgraded to Windows 10, I also upgraded my VS but after that I cannot run and build my Windows 10 app.

I downloaded the VS 2015 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx), when I chose custom install, there was no "Universal Windows App Development Tool" option as described [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/29/release-dates-and-compatibility-visual-studio-2015-and-windows-10-sdk/). I could only see a "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Phone" option.

What's wrong with my install? Am I downloading the wrong file?

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/install-dev-tools-visual-studio-2015 . Click "Add the tools" on the right. Also check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx

Comment: yes, but that is Visual Studio 2015 RC. The blog on the above link says on 29/7 I can just install VS 2015 RTM.

Comment: Did you try modifying the current Visual Studio by going to Programs and Features in the Control Panel instead of using the installer?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 RTM will only work when the final Windows 10 SDK is available, although as of writing this comment Windows 10 is available the SDK will be a few hours later - probably to ease load on CDN

Comment: Just curious, did you managed to get something working? On my setup I can create and compile "Universal App" without any error. Then I try deploy and VS says 'deploy' failed. I don't know yet where to look for the reason why it won't deploy. For now the only message I am aware of is:

`1>------ Deploy started: Project: App12, Configuration: Debug x86 -----`

`  ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

` ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: @Rastikan, for the first time after successfully installed VS 2015, I also couldn't get it deployed. I had to start a new project and copy all the things to the new project, and it got deployed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the new tools just came out a few hours ago, you can get the tools through this links :

1. [For VS 2015 Community](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=534599)
2. [For VS 2015 Professional](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=619628)
3. [For VS 2015 Enterprise](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=619629)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Install the Windows 10 SDK (Build 10240)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/F/E1F1E61E-F3C6-4420-A916-FB7C47FBC89E/standalonesdk/sdksetup.exe) and the [Windows 10 Developer Tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/1/4011ECDA-7484-4CEA-A53E-6C73A32A6793/Windows_VSTools.exe). No you see the Universal Template Items in the `New Project` dialog.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the latest SDK which was released yesterday for Windows 10 Final Version. http://dev.windows.com --> SDK Download

Answer (score -1):

[From the Microsoft website](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs):

> Note: This release does not support developing for Windows 10 until July 29. Continue to use Visual Studio 2015 RC until July 29 if you are developing Universal Windows apps.

I guess it hasn't been updated *yet*. Perhaps depending on country, location, or installing an update that is to be released today.

Comment: The question is specifically asked for RC and not RTM.

Comment: He states he _was_ using RC, and upgraded to win10 and he upgraded his visual studio aswell. Microsoft probably hasn't activated nor updated the Win10 apps for that version. Its still only enabled for the RC. If you follow the link to where he downloaded it and click Visual Studio 2015 on the left, you see my source link. It cleary states it.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it was a time/date problem: I modified my VisualStudio 2015 just a second ago: the universal tools option appeared and installed. Look at [channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2015-Final-Release-Event/Intro-to-Universal-Windows-Platform) for instructions.