# Error Building Win10 App on VS 2015 after updating

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

After updating to Windows 10 and to Visual Studio 2015 from its RC, I can't build my windows 10 app in development. The error says "error : "10.0.10069.0" is not a supported value for TargetPlatformVersion. Please change it on the Project Property page.

I clicked onto it, I see this:

```
<CheckUAPVersions TargetPlatformVersion="$(TargetPlatformVersion)" TargetPlatformMinVersion="$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)" SDKIdentifier="$(SDKIdentifier)" SDKVersion="$(SDKVersion)" />
```

But don't know what to change.

On my package.appxmanifest, I have

```
 <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10069.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `appxmanifest`, set them both to `10.0.0.0`. The RTM toolset injects the correct version when building.

Then in your project properties, make sure to set the target toolset version property to `10.0.10240.0` for All Configurations and All Platforms.

Comment: it doesn't work on Severity

Code Description Project File Line
Error  "10.0.0.0" is not a supported value for TargetPlatformVersion. Please change it on the Project Property page. poc C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\JavaScript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.UAP.targets 64

Comment: With VS 2015 RTM, the same is true for a JavaScript project: ``package.appxmanifest`` contains ``<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />`` which is updated by the build to match the *Target version* and *Min version* setting in the General properties for the project. Currently this results in a ``AppxManifest.xml`` that contains ``<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" />`` Again, make sure you are using the final released version and not a Technical Preview or RC.

Comment: @AlanLee: I'm having the same problem with a Cordova project. Did you find a solution for your JavaScript project?

Answer (score 2):

In your solution explorer, right click the UWP project directory and choose "Properties". Then, on the "Target Version" and "Min Version" field, click the drop down button and choose the target platform version based on your sdk, not "inherit from parent or project defaults".

Answer (score 0):

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31705693/775359

This post on the forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-problem-running-windows-platform-on-windows-10/30216/6

In other words **Windows 10 SDK is required**: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

*(also remember to update your Windows 10)*